# Ищу возможность

Tags: java, алгоритм, структуры-данных

```
package folder1.myutil1;

/**
 * Created by Bahodir on 14.03.2020.
 */
public class IndexedTree {
    private boolean[] exist = null;
    private int[] count = null;
    private int size = 0;
    private int allSize = 0;

    public IndexedTree(int size) {
        if (size < 0) return;
        allSize = size;
        exist = new boolean[size];
        count = new int[size];
    }

    public void add(int key) {
        if (key < 0 || key >= allSize || exist[key]) return;
        size++;
        int low = 0;
        int high = allSize - 1;
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            count[mid]++;
            if (mid < key)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (mid > key)
                high = mid - 1;
            else {
                exist[mid] = true;
                return;
//                return mid; // key found
            }
        }
//        return -(low + 1);  // key not found.
    }

    public int count() {
        if (exist == null || exist.length < 0) return 0;
        int mid = (allSize - 1) >>> 1;
        return count[mid];
    }

    public Integer getByIndex(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) return null;
        int c = index + 1;
        int low = 0;
        int high = allSize - 1;
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            int leftCount = low <= mid - 1 ? count[(low + mid - 1) >>> 1] : 0;
            if (leftCount >= c) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else {
                c -= leftCount;
                if (!exist[mid]) {
                    low = mid + 1;
                } else if (c == 1) {
                    return mid;
                } else {
                    c--;
                    low = mid + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void remove(int key) {
        if (key < 0 || key >= allSize || !exist[key]) return;
        size--;
        int low = 0;
        int high = allSize - 1;
        while (low <= high) {
            int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
            count[mid]--;
            if (mid < key)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (mid > key)
                high = mid - 1;
            else {
                exist[mid] = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот пример использования этого класса

```
import folder1.myutil1.IndexedTree;

public class Main1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        IndexedTree tree = new IndexedTree(100);
        tree.add(95);
        tree.add(30);
        tree.add(44);
        tree.add(99);
        tree.add(1);
        for(int i = 0; i < tree.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(tree.getByIndex(i));
        }
        System.out.println("После удаления");
        tree.remove(44);
        for(int i = 0; i < tree.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(tree.getByIndex(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Вот результат

```
1
30
44
95
99
После удаления
1
30
95
99
```

Этот класс я придумал для своего одного проекта, кто понял как работает это класс, скажите кто до меня изобрёл такой подход.

ВОПРОС ВТОРОЙ И ОСНОВНОЙ.
Я хочу создать несколько сортированных списков в одном фиксированном месте на памяти компьютера.
Я знаю как реализовать используя алгоритмы для сбалансирования дерева.
Код который приведен вверху IndexedTree разработанной мной, в этом классе не используется алгоритмы для сбалансирования дерева. Но с помощью такого подхода можно создать только один список, а мне нужно много списков.

Повторяю если вы не сможете мне помочь, я этого могу добиться используя алгоритмы для сбалансирования дерева, и этот подход тоже будет оригинальным и будет работать быстро.
Просто решился задать вопрос, а может существует более простой подход, учитывая что значения в списке будет только цифры от 0 до 20млн например и список будет отсортированным.

Comment: [Дерево отрезков](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) умеет такие штуки. Ваше дерево - частный случай дерева отрезков для числа элементов на отрезке.

Comment: Итерацию по вашему дереву можно устроить эффективнее. Ваш способ работает за `NlogN` для заполненого дерева. А можно обойтись `N`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy
Чтобы объяснить. Приведу пример где я это применил. На проекте где это использовано, было раздел понравившиеся публикации. Представим 2 милиона понравившиеся публикации, раздел разделен на страницы, в одном странице 24 публикации. Получается 83334 страниц. Пользователь часто обрашается к страницам которых состоит из 24 публикаций.

Comment: Дело в том что частая удаления добавления в раздел понравившиеся публикации. Чтобы каждый раз не построить индекс, использовано такой подход, итерировать 24 раза чтобы подать одну страницу, это происходит очень быстро. А построить список заново состояший из почти 2 милиона это очень медленно. Думаю смог объяснить

Comment: @Volodarskiy Спасибо, ознакомлюсь потом скажу мнение